# How can i find just the cidr notation from a terminal command?

Tags: terminal, command, notation, cidr

I am writing a script that needs to replace the network cidr notation in the command with the one found by running a command . Is there a specific command that can tell me just the cidr notation for my network so i can then turn it into a variable and then use it in a command...... any help would be great...

Comment: Found this one.... works but does not show the /     .......

Comment: ip addr show |grep -w inet |grep -v 127.0.0.1|awk '{ print $2}'| cut -d "/" -f 2

Comment: This one shows your loopback cidr and ur local area network cidr...

Comment: ip addr | awk '/inet / {sub(/\/.*/, "", $1); print $2}' | cut -d "/" -f 2